# How do I return a character an inputted number of times?

Tags: java

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class myLine {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String CurrentLine = new String();
    int length =0;

     Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int x = sc.nextInt();

        if (CurrentLine.charAt(0) == 'l') {
            return '*' x times;
        }
    }

}
```

The last line is just me taking note of what I want to do.  If the user puts in a number for x, how do I return the * character that many times?

Comment: Did you miss some code when you copied and pasted? You talk about returning, but you didn't post any method that returns anything. Where are you trying to return a String to?

Comment: Oh like I said, the last line means nothing code-wise. It's just there to remind me that I want to return a character x number of times which is what I don't know how to do

Answer (score 0):

You can't return in `main` (it's a `void` method). You aren't using `length`, and if I understand your question you could use a `StringBuilder` and a simple `for` loop. Then print the contents of the `StringBuilder`. Something like

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int x = sc.nextInt();
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < x; i++) {
        sb.append('*');
    }
    System.out.println(sb.toString());
}
```